# Good way to parse error object in catch(e) statement after API call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When using an api I often find myself with a rather complicated error object.

[image]

Depending on the API that I am using the error texts are quite helpful and I would actually sometimes like to display them directly to the user. The problem, of course, is that the error objects can look quite differently so it would be very verbose to go through them and pick individual objects in case they exists (dependant on the status code of the error).

Is this just the nature of the error object or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What I do to handle API calls that end up with error is this:

```
try {
    const response = await axios.post("Your URL");
    // Your code to handle the result
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response.data.error)
    // Code to display the error to the user
}
```

error.response.data.error is the actual error **message** sent from the server, not the error code

Comment: `Console` should be `console` - `JavaScript` is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks! Was typing quickly and apparently made it an uppercase. Edited answer to fix the mistake now.